# Duplicating Results when using Subquery, need to filter out Nulls and only show value if value exists

Tags: sql-server-2012

(Edited) I am having a problem with duplicating results when using a Count() Function and then Grouping by a column that changes from Null to having a value. See Below:

Here is a sample table of data:

```
t_order_table
  Line#     Order       User_Assigned
  1         12345       Null
  2         12345       Null
  3         12345       Null
  4         12345       Null
  5         12345       Null
  6         12345       Null
  7         12345       Null
  8         12345       Null
  9         12345       Null
  1         11223       Null
  2         11223       Null
  3         11223       Null
```

Here is the script to report on the table(below):

```
Select Order,
(Select Count(Line#) from t_order_table ord
    Where User_Assigned is null
    and o.Order = ord.Order) as 'Open Lines',
(Select Count(Line#) from t_order_table ord
    Where User_Assigned is not null
    and o.Order = ord.Order) as 'Picked Lines',
(Select User_Assigned from t_order_table ord
    Where o.Order = ord.Order) as 'User Assigned'
from t_order_table o
Group By Order, User_Assigned
```

Which Returns:

```
Order   Open Lines  Picked Lines    User_Assigned
12345       9           0               Null
11223       3           0               Null
```

As a worker logs into the system, he gets assigned to the lines, one by one as he picks the order. After he picks 3 lines, the table would look like this:

```
t_order_table
  Line#     Order       User_Assigned
  1         12345       Chris
  2         12345       Chris
  3         12345       Chris
  4         12345       Null
  5         12345       Null
  6         12345       Null
  7         12345       Null
  8         12345       Null
  9         12345       Null
  1         11223       Null
  2         11223       Null
  3         11223       Null
```

and the report would look like this:

```
Order   Open Lines  Picked Lines    User_Assigned
12345       9           3               Null
12345       9           3               Chris
11223       3           0               Null
```

The Result has a duplicated record because the SubSelect Query for 'User_Assigned' found a null and a user, so there is two records. I would like there to be some logic that checks if a user is assigned, it returns the user, else returns null. I can't figure out how to do that. Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0):

This seems to give you what you need.

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;

declare @OrderTable as table
(
    [Line] tinyint,
    [Order] int,
    [User_Assigned] nvarchar(50)
);
insert into @OrderTable
(
    [Line],
    [Order],
    [User_Assigned]
)
values
(1, 12345, 'Chris'),
(2, 12345, 'Chris'),
(3, 12345, 'Chris'),
(4, 12345, null),
(5, 12345, null),
(6, 12345, null),
(7, 12345, null),
(8, 12345, null),
(9, 12345, null),
(1, 11223, null),
(2, 11223, null),
(3, 11223, null);

select 
    o.[Order],
    sum(iif(o.User_Assigned is null, 1, 0)) as [OpenLines],
    sum(iif(o.User_Assigned is not null, 1, 0)) as [PickedLines],
    max(o.User_Assigned) as [User_Assigned]
from @OrderTable as [o]
group by
    o.[Order]
```

Returns:

```
Order   OpenLines   PickedLines User_Assigned
11223   3           0           NULL
12345   6           3           Chris
```